# "Prices vary state to state" vs. "prices vary from state to state"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> - Prices vary state to state.
> - Prices vary from state to state.

Is either more appropriate or ungrammatical?

Comment: I deleted the second question because a) we prefer to have one question per question and b) it is way too basic for this site. It could be a better fit on our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversationally, "*Prices vary state to state*" is perfectly OK, as "from" should be optional in this case. Formally, however, "*prices vary from state to state*" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

*Prices vary state to state* is almost certainly found, but, if you want to be above censure, *Prices vary from state to state* is the one to use.

Comment: There are thousands of instances of [vary](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22vary+day+to+day%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) / [change day to day](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22change+day+to+day%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. The idea that eliding *"from"* in such constructions is somehow "incorrect" seems rather anal to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I wasn't passing judgement. Just offering pragmatic advice.

Comment: I don't *think* I was passing judgement on your answer as such - just making the (additional) point that I personally wouldn't be too concerned about avoiding censure from anyone who wanted to take issue with the shortened form. It seems to me more a "neutral" issue of style, rather than a choice of phrasing from which someone might draw conclusions about your linguistic competence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Understood.

Comment: On reflection, I suppose it's obvious that at least *some* people would say *the full form is the "correct" form*, so your answer itself is "above censure", in that it acknowledges that fact without explicitly supporting the position. So +1 for what I now see as a solidly descriptivist stance!